# How to prevent DIV wrapping on the second row?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, frontend

I'm trying to make a very simple list of cards, there should be 3 cards in each row with a 20 pixels gap between them. Thus, each card should occupy 1/3 of the parent container. But for some reason, when I decrease the size of the browser window, the 3rd card moves to the second row. How can I prevent this?

```css
.parent{
  border: solid green 1px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 100px;
  gap: 20px;
}
.child{
  width: 32.2%;
  border: solid blue 1px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change in your parent container `flex-wrap: nowrap;` And the item width you can change to 100%;

```css
.parent{
  border: solid green 1px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 100px;
  gap: 20px;  
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.child{
  width: 100%;
  border: solid blue 1px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

### UPDATE

With `flex-basis`

```css
.parent{
  border: solid green 1px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 100px;
  gap: 20px;  
  box-sizing: border-box;
  justify-content: space-between;
  
}
.child{
  flex-basis: 30%;
  border: solid blue 1px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>  
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! The problem is that in my case it is a dynamic unordered list, so I need to make list items wrap to the next row if there are more than 3 items in the list. Is there any workaround?

Comment: I used divs just for the simplicity of the example. In my case, it is <ul> <li> with custom styling. Is there any solution that would not include flex-wrap: nowrap?

Comment: @Rumata Yes you can use flex-basis: . I updated my answer

Comment: Thank you yes this is almost exactly what I need!! Is there a way to remove the gap on the left and right (so that <li> items would touch the boundaries of the <ul> parent on the sides)?

Comment: @Rumata . You welcome . You can try with `justify-content: space-between;` i updated my answer too

Comment: @Rumata better use space-between;

Comment: Sorry one last question :) If I have 5 items in the list, they will jump to the opposite corners because of space-between style. Is there a way to make them stick to the left?

Comment: @Rumata You can delete justify-content. But then the children would no longer be centred. To re-centre them you would have to put a wrapper over the parent that centres the parent element.

Comment: Thank you! I also asked a new question because it seems I didn't include all my requests in the original question here and started to demand more and more features :) Your answer was super helpful thank you so much! The final solution I'll use is here, it includes responsiveness: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71802072/need-a-responsive-solution-for-wrapping-3-list-items-per-row

Answer (score 3):

`flex-wrap: nowrap;` should do the trick for you. You can set the width for the children by doing `calc(100% / 3);`. For this to work, remove the fixed width of `1000px` on the parent.

```css
.parent{
  border: solid green 1px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  height: 100px;
  gap: 10px;
}
.child{
  width: calc(100% / 3);
  border: solid blue 1px;
  background-color: blue;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Using `ul`:

```css
.parent {
  border: solid green 1px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 100px;
  gap: 10px;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-inline-start: 0;
}

.child {
  border: solid blue 1px;
  background-color: blue;
  flex-basis: 31%;
}
```

```html
<ul class="parent">
  <li class="child"></li>
  <li class="child"></li>
  <li class="child"></li>
  <li class="child"></li>
  <li class="child"></li>
  <li class="child"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hehe - simultaneous . but your ansear include te calc() of the width. it is better as mine.

Comment: Thank you! The problem is that in my case it is a dynamic unordered list, so I need to make list items wrap to the next row if there are more than 3 items in the list. Is there any workaround?

Comment: I used divs just for the simplicity of the example. In my case, it is <ul> <li> with custom styling. Is there any solution that would not include flex-wrap: nowrap?

Comment: @Rumata just added a second solution using `ul`. Should work the same, just need to add a few extra styles.

Comment: @Kameron Thank you but the problem is that there will be more than 3 items in the list, and I need it to continue on the next row (3 <li> items per row). With this styling, new items will try to fit in the same row, while I need them to wrap.

Comment: @Rumata See edits with more items.

Comment: @Kameron Thanks but it shows 2 items per row, I need 3 per row.

Comment: @Kameron The second answer resolved it for me, but Your answer was super helpful as well - I didn't know that there is such thing as  calc(100% / 3) - this is super helpful! Thank you!

Comment: @Kameron The new version is almost what I need. If there are 5 items in the list it will stick to the left side - this is what I need! But the only problem - if I resize the screen it again wraps into 2 rows, which was the initial problem.

Comment: Ones again thank you so much! This example helped me a lot and I discovered something new that I will use now in styling! the final solution I will use for this particular example is here, it includes responsiveness as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71802072/need-a-responsive-solution-for-wrapping-3-list-items-per-row